# Can I call a custom runtime component from a web worker in a Windows 10 (UWP) app

Tags: javascript, c#, windows-10, uwp, web-worker

We are planning to write an Universal Windows Platform app for Windows 10 in JavaScript.

We will need to write as well some custom runtime components, most likely in C#.

I know it is possible to call a custom runtime component from the main UI thread. Now the question is:

In is possible to call a custom runtime component from within a **Web Worker**?

Does it require some special configuration/settings/api?

Thanks!
Juan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is possible to call a custom runtime component from within a Web Worker?

I've made a basic Demo. The custom runtime component works well for Web Worker.

What I've done:

1. I created a custom runtime component and reference it in my js-based UWP Project. Then I revised the Class1.cs to Example.cs like below:

   ```
   public sealed class Example
   {
       public static string GetAnswer()
       {
           return "This is Answer";
       }
   }
   ```
2. In my js-based UWP Project I revised main.js like below:

   ```
   // Your code here!
   (function () {
       "use strict"
       var w;
       if (typeof Worker !== "undefined")
       {
           var w = new Worker("ms-appx:///js/webWorkerDemo.js");
           w.onmessage = function (evt)
           {
               document.getElementById("myContent").innerText = evt.data;
               w.terminate();
           }
       }
   })();
   ```

   and put myContent div in index.html:

   ```
   <body>
       <div id="myContent"></div>
       <script src="js/main.js"></script>
   </body>
   ```
3. I added webWorkerDemo.js under js folder, which did nothing but call the runtime component's GetAnswer method and postMessage:

   ```
     var str = MyRuntimeComponent.Example.getAnswer();
     postMessage(str);
   ```

When the app runs, "This is Answer" shows correctly in the app. So it should be no problem when using custom runtime component within a Web Worker.

And Here is the complete Sample: [WinJSSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/WinJSSample).

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a great answer.